# Restore deleted files

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, partitioning

I have a `C:\` with 24 GB free and **Unallocated space** with 397 GB free.

The **Unallocated space** contained my files until it was deleted.

Now, I have used a data recovery software, and am able to view the required files. I have about **87 GB** of data to be backed up.

I do not have any external or removable media of that capacity. Also, as said, my `C:\` has space for only 24 GB of them. Will it be still possible for me to restore the same to the unallocated space or by creating a **Simple Volume** without overwriting any of the required data?

Or, is it possible to do a **recovery of the entire partition in place?** (Something like **Undo - Redo**?

I have not switched off my laptop, have a **Live CD** as well. I do not want to simply follow the tutorials on the net and put my data at risk.

Comment: how was the space unallocated? I'd probably try testdisk from windows, and see if the partition is detected, and use that to restore

Comment: I right clicked on the the drive from the Disk Management and in the pretext of shrinking the partition, deleted it. Also, I did try TestDisk, but it says: "The following partitions can't be recovered".

Comment: But, 3-4 recovery software have been able to list all the data I need. I just have to provide a destination to the files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"I do not have any external or removable media of that capacity." Then borrow one. Or buy one. Don't, I repeat, **don't write to the HDD where your data is.** It's *always* a bad idea.

In this particular case, we don't know for sure how the data was laid out in the now unallocated space. It isn't certain that it was contiguous. You could create a new partition at the beginning (or end) of the unallocated space and end up overwriting some data.

The only safe way to recover data is to write it in a non-affected partition; to be really worry-free the better way is to write to a new HDD.

Comment: Thanks, will creating something like an image suffice, so that I can restore my contents back from the image, when I find one?

Comment: @Gathan I don't know. I've never tried it.